# how to develop wordpress menu like wwe.com menu?

Tags: wordpress-theming, drop-down-menu

I would like to design and develop wordpress menu like wwe.com menu where it has multi-column and images and video section in drop down menus.

Is it possible in wordpress?

I can create multi-column menu but not sure how to do display images and videos. I want my client will be able to add/remove videos, images in menu. just like menu in wwe.com site.

Any help will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the [UberMenu](http://wpmegamenu.com/) plugin, I think it's exactly what you're looking for.